# Making a vertical table accessible

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility, wai-aria

I have some very basic data, like this:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "city": "Minneapolis",
  "state": "Minnesota",
  "country": "United States",
  "age": "42"
}
```

I need to display it like this:

```
| name    | John Doe      |
| city    | Minneapolis   |
| state   | Minnesota     |
| country | United States |
| age     | 42            |
```

As you can see the table above has the headers left justified and the row values are all aligned.

[According to W3](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/one-header/#table-with-header-cells-in-the-first-column-only), the way to do a vertical table is like the snippet below, but they also call out:

> Note: Some screen readers will read “Date – Event – Venue” in the “Venue” cell because the direction of the `<th>` elements is ambiguous.

```css
table th {
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>John Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>City</th>
    <td>Minneapolis</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>State</th>
    <td>Minnesota</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <td>United States</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Age</th>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My question is how accessible is a vertical table like this, and would I be better off using a `<ul>` with some flexbox or grid magic to get my styling requirements and setting the data as a list? Is there an alternative I'm not considering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tables are *absolutely* accessible to screen readers when coded properly.  The only thing missing in your example (and the W3 example) is the scope of the `<th>`.  You should **always** specify the `scope` attribute so that it specifically says if the table header is for a row or a column.  Don't rely on the browser or the screen reader to "guess" at the meaning when you leave `scope` out.

There is nothing ambiguous about the direction of the header when `scope` is specified.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Name</th>
    <td>John Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">City</th>
    <td>Minneapolis</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">State</th>
    <td>Minnesota</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Country</th>
    <td>United States</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Age</th>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now when a screen reader user navigates to a data cell, for example "Minneapolis", and then they navigate to the next cell down using a table navigation key (such as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>downarrow</kbd>), they will hear the row label announced first and then the data cell value, such as "State, Minnesota".

Comment: Perfect. I had a feeling that something was missing from the example and this helps with the clarity of how it works together with a screenreader.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's not multiple people and you're listing key/value pairs, a [description list element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) would be more appropriate than a table element.

> The **`<dl>`** HTML element represents a description list. The element encloses a list of groups of terms (specified using the `<dt>` element) and descriptions (provided by `<dd>` elements). Common uses for this element are...to display metadata (a list of key-value pairs).

```css
dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto auto;
  justify-content: start;
  column-gap: 1ch;
}
dd {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>name</dt>
  <dd>John Doe</dd>
  <dt>city</dt>
  <dd>Minneapolis</dd>
  <dt>state</dt>
  <dd>Minnesota</dd>
  <dt>country</dt>
  <dd>United States</dd>
  <dt>age</dt>
  <dd>42</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: A `<dl>` seems logical and it's a semantic element so it *should be* good for accessibility, but unfortunately screen readers (SR) don't support them well. A `<dl>` with 3 pairs of `<dt>`/`<dd>` elements is a list of 3 items but some SRs say it has 6 items (which it *kind of* does). And navigating with the SR I (eye) key typically only goes to the `<dt>` element and won't go to the `<dd>`. VoiceOver (iOS) has good/bad support. VO says *"description list start"* and *"term"* and *"definition"* as you swipe to each element but will not find the list if you set your rotor to navigate by lists.

Comment: @slugolicious Thanks, that's good to know.